# Spring Data- how to tell spring what entities to retrieve

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

If i have several entites, lets say :

```
@Entity
class Book{
String name;
Author author; 
}

@Entity
class Author{
String name;
City hometown;
}

@Entity
class City{
String cityName;
}
```

If i want to retrieve all the books, if i use classic JPA Repository and Spring Data and just do a `findAll()`, it will get me all the books with all the Authors with all their home towns. I know i can use `@JsonIgnore`, but i think that only prevents whats being returned, not whats being looked up in the database. And also i have methods that DO want to return both books and authors, so `@JsonIgnore` -ing does not work for me. Is there anything like this ? To tell Spring Data what to look up and what to return ? Any links or guides or methods i don't know of, would be appreciated.

Comment: Spring Data offers Projections.https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: @AlanHay hey projections is what i was looking for, feel free to make it an answer and i will accept it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data has the concept of 'projections' which allow you to return different representations of the same Entity.

Official Documentation:

> Spring Data query methods usually return one or multiple instances of
>   the aggregate root managed by the repository. However, it might
>   sometimes be desirable to create projections based on certain
>   attributes of those types. **Spring Data allows modeling dedicated
>   return types, to more selectively retrieve partial views of the
>   managed aggregates.**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Where a Projection is a 'closed' projection (a projection interface whose accessor methods all match properties of the target aggregate) then the documentation notes that additionally:

> Spring Data can optimize the query execution [to select only the relevant fields], because we know about
>   all the attributes that are needed to back the projection proxy

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.closed

Spring Data also allows for Projections to be specified dynamically at runtime. See further:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/repository-projections.adoc#dynamic-projections

Answer (score 0):

- First mark your relations as LAZY
- Then specify what data needs to be fetched on a per-query basis.

See for example:
https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/